# How to use multiple text fields in widget "image" in content type

Tags: entities, media

I'm new in Drupal and I'm working on a website built in Drupal. I want to use multiple text fields like title, medium, photo credits with image widget in content type. I have attached two screen-shots to make clear what I really want to do.
[image]
[image]

Please help to find out the way to do this. I'll be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on [Image Field Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption) module.

Adds an extra text area for captions on image fields.

Similar to the alt and title text fields available with an image field, the caption text area can be used to enter text or html descriptions of an image.

[Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module also work for you.

Comment: but I need to add 3 or more fields. Is it possible with Media module?